# I can not partition disk space that I want

Tags: partitioning

I have disk with a capacity of 440 GB. When I select a volume and use the shrink volume button it only allows shrinking by 149 G.

I want to do two partitions of 150 GB each and one partition in the 140GB remaining space.  Total three partitions with additional one recovery drive.

How can I do that?

Comment: Wich OS you use? With what app did you use? ..

Comment: Please clarify your question and provide some information/snapshot about the current allocation of partition

Comment: I assume you did basic research and that you are not trying to shrink a volume with data on it near the end of that volume.

Comment: sometimes defragmenting the data , aligning it all to the first of the disk, can allow for shrinks that would otherwise fail. Before messing with any of it you really want to have a backup. They make partitioning programs that solution all of the problems that can exist, that could be better than trying to do it in the OS. once you have a proper and full backup , if all else fails with a full backup  you could start over again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to partition C:\ Drive as per needs in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/356508/not-able-to-partition-c-drive-as-per-needs-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. First, ensure your data is defragmented. Run the defragmentation tool a few times if necessary. (WARNING: Do not defragment SSD's. This shortens their lifespan.) The disk tool (most all of them) will only allow you to shrink a volume back to the last block of data on the disk. Next you'll want to make sure you have the space. Remember that the file system consumes a portion of your raw disk space as well. For example, you may only get 94GB off a 100GB hard drive after formatting. There have been lawsuits over this in the past... I hope this answers your question.